# How to divide the video into 3 parts, adjust the speed and merge them?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

I have a video rendering code but I don't know how to divide the video into 3 parts 1-5s 6-10s and the rest to adjust the speed and then combine it.

```
ffmpeg -y -i "{input}" -ss 1 -filter_complex "scale=1080:1920,setpts=PTS/1.1;[0:a]atempo=1.1" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 60 -g 120 -b:v 1400k -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -metadata title="" -metadata artist="" -metadata album_artist="" -metadata album="" -metadata date="" -metadata track="" -metadata genre="" -metadata publisher="" -metadata encoded_by="" -metadata copyright="" -metadata composer="" -metadata performer="" -metadata TIT1="" -metadata TIT3="" -metadata disc="" -metadata TKEY="" -metadata TBPM="" -metadata language="eng" -metadata encoder="" -threads 0 -preset superfast "{output}"
```

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1072713/